# Netbeans system build fail

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

i have a question regarding netbeans build fail
During netbeans deployed, this happened.

```
Updating property file: 

    C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystemLibrary\build\built-clean.properties

Deleting directory C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystemLibrary\build
    C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:212: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem-ejb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:789: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystemLibrary\nbproject\build-impl.xml:912: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystemLibrary\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1394: Unable to delete file C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystem\OnlineAuctionSystemLibrary\dist\OnlineAuctionSystemLibrary.jar
```

Server log from glassfish during deployment of system.

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [OnlineAuctionSystem]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve reference [Remote ejb-ref name=ejb.session.singleton.DataInitializationSessionBean/employeeControllerLocal,Remote 3.x interface =ejb.session.stateless.EmployeeControllerLocal,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session] because there are [2] ejbs in the application with interface ejb.session.stateless.EmployeeControllerLocal. 
Some of the possible causes: 
1. The EJB bean class was packaged in an ear lib library (or through any other library mechanism which makes the library visible to all component modules), this makes all the component modules include this bean class indirectly. 
2. The EJB bean class was packaged in a component module which references the EJB, either directly or indirectly through Manifest, WEB-INF/lib. 
The EJB bean class should only be packaged in the declaring ejb module and not the referencing modules. The referencing modules should only include EJB interfaces.
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ComponentValidator.accept(ComponentValidator.java:356)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2855)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2843)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:115)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:625)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:757)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:625)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:703)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:248)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:193)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [OnlineAuctionSystem] : Cannot resolve reference [Remote ejb-ref name=ejb.session.singleton.DataInitializationSessionBean/employeeControllerLocal,Remote 3.x interface =ejb.session.stateless.EmployeeControllerLocal,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session] because there are [2] ejbs in the application with interface ejb.session.stateless.EmployeeControllerLocal. 
Some of the possible causes: 
1. The EJB bean class was packaged in an ear lib library (or through any other library mechanism which makes the library visible to all component modules), this makes all the component modules include this bean class indirectly. 
2. The EJB bean class was packaged in a component module which references the EJB, either directly or indirectly through Manifest, WEB-INF/lib. 
The EJB bean class should only be packaged in the declaring ejb module and not the referencing modules. The referencing modules should only include EJB interfaces.
```

I keep on meeting this error. What i did previously to resolve it was to go to the folder and delete the jar file myself. I also stop/terminated glass fish server and undeployed the client & the system.
May i know how do i resolve it? And what can be done about this?

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept on thinking that it was because the library jar file was locked. But someone helped me and told me about this line in my error code

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve reference [Remote ejb-ref name=ejb.session.singleton.DataInitializationSessionBean/employeeControllerLocal,Remote 3.x interface =ejb.session.stateless.EmployeeControllerLocal,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session] because there are [2] ejbs in the application with interface ejb.session.stateless.EmployeeControllerLocal.
```

What happened was that i had another controller, CustomerControllerLocal using the same local and remote sessionbeans.

Eg: This is employee controller class.

```
@Stateless
@Local(CustomerControllerLocal.class)  //I should put EmployeeControllerLocal
@Remote(Customer ControllerRemote.class) //Same goes for here, remote.

public class EmployeeController implements EmployeeControllerRemote, EmployeeControllerLocal {
 //ommited the rest
}
```

Small and careless mistake! Thanks everyone for viewing this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what problem is, if possible share the log.
You can try this: Go to properties of your project --> Libraries and remove this jar file if you are not using it.
I am just guessing it. Share some more details.